# R empty data frame after subsetting by factor

Tags: r, split, subset, r-factor

I need to subset my data depending on the content of one factor variable.
I tried to do it with subset:

```
new <- subset(data, original$Group1=="SALAD")
```

*data* is already a subset from a bigger data frame, in *original* I have the factor variable which should identify the wanted rows.
This works perfectly for one level of the factor variable, but (and I really don´t understand why!!) when I do it with the other factor level "BREAD" it creates the data frame but says "**no data available**" - so it is empty. I´ve imported the data from SPSS, if this matters. I´ve already checked the factor levels, but the naming should be right!

Would be really grateful for help, I spent 3 hours on this problem and wasn´t able to find a solution.
I´ve also tried other ways to subset my data (e.g. *split*), but I want a data frame as output.

Do you have advice in general, what is the best way to **subset a data frame** if I want e.g. 3 columns of this data frame and these should be **extracted depending on the level of a factor** (most Code examples are only for one or all columns..)

Comment: And we would be grateful for some sample data :)

Comment: Please share your data. There is no reason `"SALAD"` should work but not `"BREAD"`. Posting `str(data)` and `dput(head(data))` will help us find out what is going on.

Comment: (1) You don't need the dollar sign `$` inside `subset`; `subset(data, Group1 == "SALAD")` should work. (2) In your code line above, you are using one `data.frame` (`data`) but are subsetting based on the column of *another* `data.frame` (`original`); that can be dangerous and lead to wrong results if there is no 1-to-1 mapping between `data` and `original`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use the whole dataset now (original). So I used your suggested subset code, but the problem remained. Here is what R says about the structure of the column/ factor: Factor w/ 2 levels "SALAD","BREAD": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 - attr(*, "label")= Named chr "SALAD vs nutrition"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Group1"
structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("SALAD", "BREAD"
), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = structure("SALAD vs nutrition", .Names = "Group1")). I saw now that there is also this label "nutrition"and tried to use it, but the problem remained.

Comment: So if I use test <- subset(original, Group1=="SALAD"), everything works fine, I get a data.frame with this subset. But if I use "BREAD", R shows no error but I get an empty data.frame...

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of the `subset` function (as I understand it) is to look inside the data frame for the right variable - so you can type

```
subset(data, var1 == "value")
```

instead of

```
data[data$var1 == "value,]
```

Please correct me anyone if that is incorrect.

Now, in you're case, you are explicitly taking `Group1` from the data frame `original` and using that to subset `data` - which you say is a subset of `original`.  Based on this, I see no reason to believe (and every reason not to believe) that the elements of `original$Group1` will align with the rows of `data`.  If `Group1` is defined within `data`, why not just use the copy defined there - which is aligned correctly?    If not, you need to be very explicit about what you are trying to accomplish, so that you can ensure that things are aligned correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I will change this. I´ve just done it because I didn´t know how to extract only 5 columns of original with subset and I had these 5 columns in data. Is it possible to extract only 5 columns with subset (and by factor level)?